What does the "Full" error on a Nikon Z50 screen mean?
Has anyone experienced the Nikon Z50 error where the screen keeps blinking with the word FULL?
I can't adjust my aperture and shutter speed, only ISO. And when I look at the view, it's just black. It keeps on reading full, but my memory card is not full. Please help.

From the manual here: https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/z50/en/80_troubleshooting_03.html

Message: Full (flashes)
Memory insufficient to record further pictures at current settings, or
camera has run out of file or folder numbers.  Reduce quality or size.
Delete pictures after copying important images to computer or other
device. Insert new memory card.

So either your memory card is full (deleting the images on the pc might not free memory on the card) or you have used all the index numbers that the camera can write, so there are no file names left or there is something broken in the camera that needs maintenance. My gut feeling would be the first thing.
Just a note in case: If you continually store all your images on the sd card, please absolutely stop doing this. SD cards are relatively robust, but they are not a good long term storage. You risk losing all your images if the card fails. And almost all photographers that I know had at least one failing card in their life.
Get your images from the card, format your card in the camera with the camera function and you should be good to go. If that does not work, try out another memory card that you also format in camera. It also might be a faulty card.

I use a Nikon Zfc camera (similar category of Z50) with a 64 GB memory card (the card came with the camera purchase) and am new to digital photography. What I did from the beginning was to copy the images from the card to my PC using Nikon NX Studio free pc program for further processing. I do this after every shoot, so that I can review the pictures on a large monitor. The images are stored in different folder on the PC for each copy action. This also is a backup for me. To make space I can delete all or older images from my card anytime I want to.
If you are shooting often, and creating videos and RAW or RAW+JPEG images, a backup card and with higher storage is useful in some situations.
As already noted by @Kai Mattern, it is possibly an issue with memory card running out of space. Or even some defect. If it could not be resolved by creating more space on the card, a nearest Nikon service center can help resolve the problem.
